# Javascript - Get prototype to return generator

Tags: javascript, constructor, iterator, prototype, generator

In my current JS-project I have a *class*, which looks like this:

```
function MyClass() {
   this.prop1 = true;
   this.prop2 = "Hello World";
   this.prop3 = "This is another String.";
   this.prop4 = "Just another string here.";
}
```

I want to be able to iterate over the string using an [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). I could achieve it by doing this:

```
function* createStringIteratorFromMyClass(myclass) {
   yield myclass.prop2;
   yield myclass.prop3;
   yield myclass.prop4;
}
```

Now I'm able to iterate over the string like this:

```
for(const str createStringIteratorFromMyClass(...)) {
    // access str here
}
```

This works great, but I would like to add `createStringIteratorFromMyClass` to the prototype of `MyClass`.

Something like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.createStringIterator = function* () {
   yield this.prop2;
   yield this.prop3;
   yield this.prop4;
}
```

At this point I get the error:

> Unexpected token '*'. Expected an opening '(' before a function's
>   parameter list.

How can I add a function, which returns a generator to the prototype of my class?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you want an instance of your class to be iterable, there's no need to create an additional wrapper. Just define `Symbol.iterator` for the class:

```
function MyClass() {
   this.prop1 = true;
   this.prop2 = "Hello World";
   this.prop3 = "This is another String.";
   this.prop4 = "Just another string here.";
}

MyClass.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
   yield this.prop2;
   yield this.prop3;
   yield this.prop4;
}

let x = new MyClass()

for(const str of x) {
  console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to have multiple different iterators? Like one which iterates over the string properties and one which iterates over the integer properties?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive: in this case, your code is fine. Which transpiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what transpolar I'm using. I just stared a few days back coming from a strong `C`-background. I'm just writing *.js* files to beautify my webpages. It's strange, that the code in your *tinyurl* works, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. As [this](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) homepage states. Generators are currently not supported in Safari (which I'm using.) - now I'll have to come up with an alternative.